# Stationary spatial random filed

Tags: stationarity, spatial

I am very new to the spatial model. My question is, what does a stationary spatial random field mean? If I divide the data, say, "meuse" dataset in "sp" package in"R" into equal distance spatial bins, and assume that the marginal distribution at all locations in each spatial bins is the same, then this means that the spatial field is stationary. Is that correct?

Hence, if we divided the data into spatial bins, and fit a different marginal distribution for each bin, then this is a non-stationary model.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It means *exactly* the same thing as it does in one dimension: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=stationary+time+series.

Comment: Stationarity is a property of the model, not of observed data. In addition to whubers comment: in the spatial context, you are not looking at time lags / time shifts, but at shifts by an arbitrary vector. There are different flavors of stationarity. For strict stationarity, marginal distribution in bins is not sufficient.

Comment: @Ute thanks. Yes, for spatial, the shifts are based on the space but not time. So, for strong stationary, marginal distribution is insufficient to say that the field is non-stationary. However, it may provide more flexibility in modeling the data if we do not impose the same marginal distribution across spatial bins. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I would put it that way: if the (theoretical) marginal distributions do not coincide, we know that the field cannot be strongly stationary. If you want the distribution to differ on bins, then you have a non stationary field. As far as I can see, the original meuse data are measurement in irregular spaced points. When the location of these points are of interest, one should use spatial point process methods - there is a fairly well established theory of non stationary spatial point processes.

Comment: The basic problem with binning is that unless the bins are sufficiently large (far greater than the range of the covariance), any *estimates* of distributions within the bins *will* vary by location even with stationary processes.  Again, examining the 1D (time series) situation provides insight.  Consider an AR-1 times series process with large lag-1 correlation: any realization proceeds in regular, smooth waves. If your bins do not span several wavelengths, you are sampling the peaks and troughs of the waves separately.